# File Transfer stuck in do while loop

Tags: java, file, sockets, ftp

Hello I am trying to do a small client file server application in which any type of file can be transferred including(.txt , .JPEG, .docx, .mp3 and .wma).  So far I have been able to do the transfer only at random.  Most of the time the file is not transferred; only the image is printed on the client path.

It seems to me that the file is getting stuck in the do while loop.  Please help me to selve this out.

*Server part:*

```
    // create socket
    ServerSocket serversock = new ServerSocket(444);

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Waiting for client to connect...");
        Socket welcomesock = serversock.accept();
        System.out.println("Client has connected from: " + welcomesock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());


        File myFile = new File ("C:\\temp\\New Stories.wma");

        if(!myFile.exists()){
            System.out.println("Filename does not exist");
            welcomesock.close();
        }

        else{
            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);     

            OutputStream os = welcomesock.getOutputStream();

            System.out.println("Sending file");

            os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

            os.flush();

            os.close();

            }
        }</i>
```

Client Part:

while(true){

```
        int bytesRead;
        int currentlength = 0;
        int fsize=6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();


        // Creates the Client socket and binds to the server
        Socket clientSocket = null;

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(127.0.0.1, 444);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }




        byte [] bytearray  = new byte [fsize];
        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\New Stories.wma");

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        currentlength = bytesRead;

        do {
            bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, currentlength, (bytearray.length-currentlength));
            if(bytesRead >= 0) currentlength += bytesRead;

        } while(bytesRead > -1);

        bos.write(bytearray, 0 , currentlength);
        bos.flush();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end-start);

        bos.close();
        clientSocket.close();



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server part has an infinite loop:

```
while (true){
   ...
}
```

will never exit. You might want to change:

```
if(!myFile.exists()){
        System.out.println("Filename does not exist");
        welcomesock.close();
    }
```

to

```
if(!myFile.exists()){
        System.out.println("Filename does not exist");
        welcomesock.close();
        break;
    }
```

which will exit the loop, when no file exists.

Comment: ok will see to it  but when I try to download...the file seems to be incrementing to its actual size...however once I terminate the program...filesize is zero..

Comment: its working bro..fine bro...will tick your answer :)